# Ошибки: Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'int' и Argument 1: cannot convert from 'int' to 'string'

Tags: c#

Пытаюсь написать парсер. 
Вроде сделал всё как в уроке.
Выдаёт ошибки:
    - в строке MessageBox.Show(GetNiks(1)); - ошибка: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'int' to 'string' 
    - в строке  return nicks; - ошибка   Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'int'

Как устранить данные ошибки?

```
using xNet;

namespace rsh
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // ПАРСИНГ КОЛИЧЕСТВА СТРАНИЦ
            //string s = Convert.ToString(GetCountPages());
            //MessageBox.Show(s);

            // ПАРСИНГ НИКОВ
            // GetNiks(1);
            // MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(GetNiks(1)));
            MessageBox.Show(GetNiks(1));

        }

        // ПАРСИНГ НИКОВ
        private int GetNiks(int Num) // int Num - это номер страницы с которой мы парсим ники
        {
            // string nicks = " ";
            string nicks = "";
            try
            {
                using (var Request = new HttpRequest())
                {
                    string SourcePage; // перменная для хранения исходного кода страницы

                    string[] raw;                   

                    SourcePage = Request.Get("http://vegetarian.ru/forum/users/?PAGEN_1=" + Num).ToString();  // скачиваем исходный код страницы
                                                                                                            // countPages = Convert.ToInt32(SourcePage.Substrings("/forum/users/?PAGEN_1=", "">", 0)[4]); // парсим количество стрниц. Применённая 

                    raw = SourcePage.Substrings("title="">", "</a>", 0); // парсим количество стрниц. Применённая 
                                                                            // title = "">
                                                                            // </a>
                    for (int i=0; i < raw.Length; i++)
                    {
                        if (i%2 == 0) // если дробная часть равна нулю
                        {
                            // MessageBox.Show(i + " " + raw[i]);
                            nicks += raw[i] + "\r\n";
                        }
                    }

                }
             }
            catch
            {

            }

            // return Convert.ToInt32(nicks);
            return nicks; 

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `private string GetNiks(int Num)`

Comment: о каком уроке идет речь?

Comment: @Igor Верный ответ. Работает. Наверное оформляйте как ответ.. Если я правильно понимаю правила форума...

Comment: @Grundy Честно говоря не помню... скачал где-то видео

Comment: @koverflow, очевидно. если в указанном видео все работало, а у тебя - нет, то ты сделал не все как в уроке.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Код внутри `GetNiks` возвращает строку, а декларация говорит о том, что возвращаемое значение - `int`. Изменим декларацию, чтобы починить эту ошибку. В результате починится и ошибка вызова `MessageBox.Show`, так как ожидаемый параметр здесь - строка.

```
private string GetNiks(int Num)
{
  ...
}
```

Comment: что должен значить этот блок кода? как он относится к проблеме в вопросе? В чем была ошибка? Как она решилась?

Comment: @Grundy Вы печатаете гораздо быстрее меня :).

Comment: Ну можно же было сразу хороший ответ написать :)

Comment: @Grundy Ошибка чисто "механическая".. Не заметил..